# no module named; PyPi uploaded package

Tags: python, package, shared-libraries, setuptools, pypi

When I try to do: `from libratest.queries import predictionQueries` I get this error:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/tester/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libratest/queries/predictionQueries.py", line 22, in <module>
    from dataset_labelmatcher import get_similar_column, get_similar_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset_labelmatcher'
```

This is from a Python package that I uploaded to PyPi. If I just do `import libratest` it works.

Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
Libratest
|
| __init__.py
|
| data
|
|       __init__.py
|
| data generation
|       __init__.py
|       dataset_labelmatcher.py
|       grammartree.py
|
| dev_pipeliner
|       __init__.py
|
| LICENSE.txt
|
| modeling 
|       __init__.py
|
| plotting
|       __init__.py
|
| preprocessing
|       __init__.py
|
| queries
|       __init__.py
|       predictionQueries.py
|
| README.md
| requirements.txt
```

All of the **init**.py files are blank.

This is what my setup.py file looks like:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="libra", # Replace with your own username
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Palashio/Libra",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires= [
        'numpy',
        'sklearn',
        'keras',
        'tabulate',
        'pprint',
        'scipy',
        'pandas',
        'matplotlib'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Is the issue here where i'm specifying the packages in the setup.py file? Should I specify each package seperately? I'm just following the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`Libra/data generation/`](https://github.com/Palashio/Libra/tree/fb31ee649d8cc84e424e8cfb011489612d40303f/data%20generation) has a space in the name so it cannot be importable packages. Also there is no `__init__.py` in it despite your diagram above shows it.

These two problems make `setup.py` not include the directory in the installation package so you cannot import anything from it.